# How to remove html DOM elements from a string (with javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, meta-tags

Ok, so I'm building my angular application. I'm inserting about first 100 characters of the content to the "description" meta tag for facebook sharing, but there is a problem. It also adds the DOM html elements to the description. So the facebook description looks like this(sry, it's in Estonian):

"Mängu võib mängida koos alkoholiga või ilma. Mäng käib järgmiselt: <​ol> <​li>Kõikidele mängijatele antakse paber (soovitatavalt <​img class="lightbox_image" src="img/article_pictures/post_it_note.jpg" alt=""><​span class="lightbox_link" onclick="open_lightbox(this)">kleepuv post-it note<​/span>) ja…"

You can test it here:
http://vivule.ee/2

I tried removing the elements before inserting them into the metatags, but I can only remove so much.

Here's an example of how I remove br tags:

```
  var original_description = $scope.game.description;
  original_description = original_description.replace(/<br>/g,"");
```

But how would I remove something like this: "<​img class="lightbox_image" src="img/article_pictures/post_it_note.jpg" alt="">", is there an easier method than regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have no Idea about angularJS!!! but if you would use JQuery, then you could do it like this:

create a JQuery Element from the String you have for example:

```
var yourHtmlString = '<p>p contents</p> hallo <br/> <i>i contents</i>
    <img  src="img/article_pictures/post_it_note.jpg" alt="">';

var div = $('<div>'+yourHtmlString+'</div>');
```

and now, to get text only without html tags, just do:

`div.text();`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lxyd2joa/